# How to connect a record player to Last.fm?

Tags: vinyl

I've become an avid user of [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm/home). It's always fun to look back and see what I've streamed over the past week, month, year, etc. It provides a lot of really useful functionality that my main listening app (Spotify), doesn't provide natively.

But I've begun to use my record player more and more. And it's bugging me that Last.fm isn't logging my listens.

Is there any way to hook the player up to Last.fm?

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was "there's no way," but apparently there's a home-brewed utility called Scrobbyl that does exactly this.  You hook up your record player to your computer's audio input and run the utility, it matches the audio to a database, and posts to Last.fm.

I've never tried this so I can't vouch for it personally.

https://changelog.com/scrobbyl-automatically-scrobble-your-vinyl-collection-in/

Comment: I have some doubts about how well this app works. The code hasn't been touched since 2010, and I can't find any testimonials. As such I'm hesitant to jump in. Any anecdotes would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a lot of demand for this, so if this one doesn't work, you'd probably have to write your own.

Comment: The github link for scrobbyl is dead. Last.fm has open sourced its acoustic [fingerprinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201553/convert-mp3-to-mp3-karaoke-with-ffmpeg/29210622#29210622) at some point but it doesn't seem to work over the air. Some other libs here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269167/open-source-audio-pattern-recognition-finger-printing

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few options:

- manually scrobble your vinyl with [Vinyl Scrobbler](https://vinylscrobbler.com), [UniversalScrobbler](http://universalscrobbler.com/) or [Open Scrobbler](https://openscrobbler.com/),
- automatic vinyl scrobbling with [ShazamScrobbler](http://shazamscrobbler.com) (only works with Shazam installed on a Mac)